# check if each line from a text file startwith certain character

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\S160358\Desktop\file.txt")

Do While reader.Peek() > -1
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

    If line.EndsWith("PSTAT") Then
        Console.WriteLine("Yes")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
Loop


Sample data
    1111111111|22222222222222|3333333333|PSTAT
    2222222222|33333333333333|
    1111111111|PSTAT
    AAAAAAAAAA|DDDDDDDDDDDDDD|FFFFFFFFFF|PSTAT
```

I am trying to check if any of line not end with certain characters. If it return "No" then it will process a reformatting function. After I run this code, it will return "Yes", and it should return "No" as second row is not end with PSTAT.

Comment: The title of your question and the body of the question disagree on if the lines or the file are to start or end with a certain character or characters. Could you edit it to make it correct, please?

Comment: It seems that if any line does not `EndsWith("PSTAT")` you want to step out of the loop and return `No`. If it is so then you may either use `Return "No"` or use `Exit Do` in the `Else` block of your `If` statement as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check all the lines, then you can't determine the result until you have checked all the lines (or found a line without the ending):

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\S160358\Desktop\file.txt")
Dim anyNo As Boolean = False
Do While reader.Peek() > -1
  Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
  If Not line.EndsWith("PSTAT") Then
    anyNo = True
    Exit Do
  End If
Loop
If anyNo Then
  Console.WriteLine("No")
Else
  Console.WriteLine("Yes")
End If
Console.ReadLine()
```

Or simply:

```
Dim anyNo As Boolean = _
  File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\S160358\Desktop\file.txt") _
  .Any(Function(line) Not line.EndsWith("PSTAT"))
If anyNo Then
  Console.WriteLine("No")
Else
  Console.WriteLine("Yes")
End If
Console.ReadLine()
```